# How to do two databases relationship ( OneToOneField )

Tags: django, django-models, sqlite, django-database

if is not supported in Django?

I read from Django documentaion:

> Django doesn’t currently provide any support for foreign key or
>   many-to-many relationships spanning multiple databases.

So I have two databases
DB_1 and DB_2

DB_1:
All inserts and updates will go to the default database( DB_1 ).

DB_2 (read_only):
All read queries will go to DB_2 database

I have this class:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    free_day = models.DateField(null=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.person
```

and I'm trying to create object by using shell

```
p = Person.objects.get(username='Herehere')
t = Task(person=p,text='blabla')
t.save()
```

But I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'
```

If I change

```
person = models.OneToOneField(Person)
```

to

```
person = models.OneToOneField(Person, primary_key)
```

I got

```
'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'operators'
```

My settings.py db configurations:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'ldap': {
        'ENGINE': 'ldapdb.backends.ldap',
        'NAME': AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI,
        'USER': AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN,
        'PASSWORD': AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD,
    },
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['ldapdb.router.Router']
```

Comment: So, if there is a note about "Django doesn’t currently provide any support for foreign key spanning multiple databases", what are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't think that even SQLite supports cross-database foreign keys. You're best bet is to simulate it with an integer column that contains the primary key of whatever you're referencing, possibly creating a custom type to hide this from the code that uses it.